# Get the current value of a span

Tags: jquery

Right now upon selection of the checkboxes, it adds the assigned price, but it doesn't subtract upon de-selection. How do I properly check the amount of `$('.amount')` and then do the proper math?

I made a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/XSCZ3/13/) to display what I'm working with.

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var amount = $('.amount').html();
    sum = Number(amount.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));
    var names = $(':checked').map(function(){
        sum += (this.value - 0);
        return this.name;
    }).get().join(',');
    $('span.amount').text('$' + sum);
    spans[1].innerHTML = sum;
});
```

Comment: Make sure you are targeting the $('.amount') that is related to the checkbox that changed rather than the first one(which is what you are doing currently)

Comment: @KevinB you're right. But thats not what is causing the inability to subtract.

Comment: Surely each calculation should start from scratch with `sum = 0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about keeping track of the original amount and then always starting with that, like this:

```
var originalAmount = Number($('.amount').html().replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var sum = originalAmount;
    // The rest of the code stays the same.
```

[**updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/XSCZ3/14/)

EDIT: I forgot to point out that I added "var" in front of "sum", so it is a local variable.

Comment: Actually, `var sum` is not required: one can operate on `originalAmount` alone. But otherwise, good point, +1. )

Comment: @raina77ow - Thanks, but are you sure about not needing `sum`? Because then `originalAmount` would get changed, and it needs to stay the same.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to iterate through all of the check-boxes every time.
Using your existing logic you will keep adding the already added amounts.

In your current code when clicking the first checkbox it adds, `99.99` as expected but when clicking the second checkbox after that it adds `199.98`. `99.99` from the first again as well as the `99.99` from the second, resulting in incorrect totals.

I think you could simplify this by only working with the currently clicked value. That would also save on redundancy by not re-evaluating the already processed checkboxes, similar to this:

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    var sum = $('.amount').html();
    sum = Number(sum.replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g,""));

    if(this.checked){
        sum += Number(this.value);
    } else {
        sum -= Number(this.value);
    }

    $('span.amount').text('$' + sum);
    spans[1].innerHTML = sum;
});
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/367A2/) - Using single amount deduct/add per click

---

Answer (score 0):

It can be very simple 
I hope this can help

**KISS** `Keep It Simple Silly`

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
var amount = $('.amount').html();

amount = amount.substring(1);
var pre = parseFloat(amount); 

if ($(this).is(':checked')) {

   pre += parseFloat($(this).val()); 


} else {
    pre -= parseFloat($(this).val()); 
}
amount = pre; 


$('span.amount').text('$' + amount);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XSCZ3/15/

I hope this can help